# How to display my JSON data into table using DataTable plug-in?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

As per the document [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) ,i have implemented the server side code.

JS code

```
$('#datatable_paging').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "#### my php file path ####",
 });
```

I am getting JSON data as

```
{
    "sEcho": 0,
    "iTotalRecords": 19,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": "19",
    "aaData": [
        ["1", "peter", "peter@gmail.com"],
        ["2", "john", "john@yahoo.com"],
        ["3", "raj", "raj@in.com"],
        ["4", "selvin", "selvin@gmail.com"],
        ["5", "ismail", "ismail@gmail.com"],
        ["6", "muadth", "muad@hotmail.com"],
        ["7", "ahmed", "ahmed@gmail.com"],
       .....
    ]
}
```

Now i need to display this JSON result in below table with Datatable pagination

HTML code

```
    <table id="datatable_paging">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>                
          </tr>
        </thead>            
  </table>
```

Comment: Do not listen to answers with elaborate code changes (did they not read the link showing almost identical code?). What you have done above is fundamentally correct, and it's just a matter of figuring out where the details went wrong. Have you confirmed that the data is being returned as JSON (inspect the actual returned data, not just what you think the output of the PHP is), or is the above sample just an assumption? Have you run it through JSON Lint to make sure it's valid?

Comment: @GregPettit- i checked JSON code with JSON lint, it's valid json. Now i don't know how to display this JSON data to table. I wasted time with `samba penugonda` answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People answering this are overthinking this way too much.  Datatables will handle the output without any fancy looping/assigning/etc when you set the options correctly.  Assuming your JSON return is proper as described in the spec:

HTML:

```
 <table id="datatable_paging"></table>
```

Then the jQuery:

```
var oTable = $('#datatable_paging').dataTable( {        
        "bDestroy":true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]], 
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "#### my php file path ####",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bFilter":true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bInfo": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "Id", "sWidth": "33%"},
            { "sTitle": "Name", "sWidth": "33%"},
            { "sTitle": "Email", "sWidth": "33%"}
        ]
    })
```

The paging, etc is going to be setup properly, assuming that your PHP source is correctly filtering as it should.  If, for example, you find that you're getting 19 results when you should be getting 10, you'd know that the problem is at your source, not here in the jQuery.  In your example, the source says it's returning 19 total result out of 19 and bPaginate hasn't been specified, so that would be why the paging isn't working.  aoColumns setups your head, no need to do in HTML unless you really want to.  The other functions are well-documented on the datatables site, though ask questions if you're confused.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop though the 'aaData' and add a new row directly with fnAddData.

Check here for example: http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Edit: A example for you as well.

```
var aaData = theVariableHoldingTheJsonObject.aaData;
$("#datatable_paging").dataTable().fnAddData ( aaData )
```

That's basically it

Comment: JSON data i posted above is correct or what? Now it is showing `DataTables warning (table id = 'datatable_paging'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.`

Comment: The JSON object looks fine to me. Could you check in your console (firedebugger, inspector or something similar) and check if the ajax-resource is fetched correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should send back a correct "sEcho" variable in JSON.

It is information that DataTables needs to know about the data being sent back, in order to be able to render. You need to pass back to DataTables the value that was sent.

sEcho is described here: http://datatables.net/usage/server-side

So to get your example works change "sEcho" to 1 or better write like this:

```
"sEcho": int(request.vars['sEcho'])   #python code
```